# CefSharp exit when detecting cookie?

Tags: c#

I'm using CefSharp to ask the user to login, and I want to automatically detect when a certain URL and cookie is set.

I found this way for the cookies:

```
class webview_cookies : ICookieVisitor
    {
        public bool Visit(Cookie cookie, int count, int total, ref bool deleteCookie)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name +" = " +  cookie.Value);

            return true;
        }
    }

webview_cookies o = new webview_cookies();

            CEF.VisitAllCookies(o);
```

however CEF.VisitAllCookies is synchronous... Meaning that I won't know when the cookie is created.

What can I do?

Comment: `when...cookie is set` : do you mean detect that a cookie has been set, or detect the exact time that a cookie was set?  Also, it's asynchronous not synchronous.

Comment: no I need to trigger some function when a cookie with name "x" is created